# Keeping Element with Absolute Position inside its container in center-left

Tags: css

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.letter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <p class='letter'>A</p>
  <p class='word'>A pple</p>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <p class='letter'>B</p>
  <p class='word'>B anana</p>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <p class='letter'>C</p>
  <p class='word'>C arrot</p>
</div>
```

I know That this Design is stupid and can be made easily,

But I want to learn using it How I can I make the `.letter` position same as the **First Letter** using `position: absolute; left:0; top: 0;`,

I just want to place it in middle-left with no-padding or spacing or marging at all.

Something like `vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;` But with the effect of Absolute position of no spacing at all.

But it keeps moving all the letters to left of page above itself instead of the parent element itself after adding `left: 0;`

How can I do that?

Comment: `position: relative` on `.container`

Comment: try adding `position: relative` to `.container`

Comment: Now that fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add `position:relative` to `.container`

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.letter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <p class='letter'>A</p>
  <p class='word'>A pple</p>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <p class='letter'>B</p>
  <p class='word'>B anana</p>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <p class='letter'>C</p>
  <p class='word'>C arrot</p>
</div>
```